# How to format the rad grid string column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a rad grid with sample column given as:

```
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ApplicantSSN" 
    DataFormatString="{0:###-##-####}" 
    HeaderText="SSN/ID Number" 
    SortExpression="ApplicantSSN"
    UniqueName="ApplicantSSN">
 </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

The column in grid is displayed as simple text eg **`123456789`** but i want to show this column like  **`123-45-6789`** .

I tried `DataFormatString="{0:###-##-####}"` but it doesnot work and also tried GridMaskedColumn but does not work.

Comment: What data type is `ApplicantSSN`? If it's a string, the `DataFormatString` won't process it correctly.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It is in String. Now what should i do?

Comment: You could change the data type to `int` or format the string yourself inside the "getter" for the property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also another way to achieve this by using regular expression. Pass the Unformatted SSN in the method on grid ItemDataBound.

```
 public static string SsnInjectDashes(string ssn)
            {
                if (ssn == null)
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                }
                string value = ssn;
                Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)");
                if (re.IsMatch(ssn))
                {
                    Match match = re.Match(ssn);
                    value = match.Groups[1] + "-" + match.Groups[2] + "-" + match.Groups[3];
                }
                return value;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ItemDataBound event to handle this:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
        string originalText = dataItem["ApplicationSSN"].Text;
        dataItem["ApplicationSSN"].Text = originalText.Substring(0, 3) + "-" + originalText.Substring(3, 2) + "-" + originalText.Substring(5, 4);
    }
}
```

Of course I've written no error handling to account for SSN length being less than 9, but this should get you there.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Dataformat for Radgrid]

Dataformat strings for Radgrid

Comment: Is there a way for leading zero but only for values less then 1?